# How to update parent's state with a new object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Trying to implement a function that adds a new value to my ReactJS table.

When i click the button "cadastrar" in the Formulario component it should send a new object to the parent's component and re-render the table rows.

I'm trying really hard to make this application work, don't see why its not working propperly.

my objective with that is that the table is supposed to keep it's old values adding a new row with the new values from the forms.

**Exact error when i click the button:**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/vpT2u.jpg

*Parent's component:*

```js
import './App.css';
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {Table, Jumbotron, Button} from 'react-bootstrap'
import Formulario from './Formulario'
import renderCadastros from './renderCadastros'

function App() {
  
  const [Cadastros, setCadastros] = useState([{
    "id": 1,
    "nome": "Francisca Julia da Costa",
    "cpf": "457.696.936-65",
    "rg": "47.360.897-2",
    "data_nasc": "23/03/1944",
    "sexo": "Feminino"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "nome": "Noah Felipe Silva",
    "cpf": "956.531.431-70",
    "rg": "40.974.782-8",
    "data_nasc": "11/07/1964",
    "sexo": "Masculino"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "nome": "Alícia Rosângela Melo",
    "cpf": "066.291.353-18",
    "rg": "36.214.141-1",
    "data_nasc": "18/02/1978",
    "sexo": "Feminino"
  }]) 
  
  function atualizarCadastros(novoCadastro){
    setCadastros(cadastrosAtuais => {
      return [cadastrosAtuais, novoCadastro]
    })
  }

  return (
  
  <Jumbotron style={{background: 'transparent'}}> 
    
    <Formulario atualizarCadastros={atualizarCadastros} />

    <Table striped bordered hover size='sm'>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>id</th>
          <th>Nome</th>
          <th>CPF</th>
          <th>RG</th>
          <th>Nascimento</th>
          <th>Sexo</th>
          <th></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {Cadastros.map(renderCadastros)}
      </tbody>
    </Table>

  </Jumbotron>
  
  );
}

export default App;
```

*Component that creates the table rows based on it's parent state:*

```js
import './App.css';
import React from 'react';
import {Button} from 'react-bootstrap'

function renderCadastros(cadastro, index){
    return(
    <tr id={cadastro.id} key={index}>
        <td>{cadastro.id}</td>
        <td contentEditable="true" suppressContentEditableWarning={true}>{cadastro.nome}</td>
        <td contentEditable="true" suppressContentEditableWarning={true}>{cadastro.cpf}</td>
        <td contentEditable="true" suppressContentEditableWarning={true}>{cadastro.rg}</td>
        <td contentEditable="true" suppressContentEditableWarning={true}>{cadastro.data_nasc}</td>
        <td contentEditable="true" suppressContentEditableWarning={true}>{cadastro.sexo}</td>
        <td align="center"><Button variant="danger">Excluir</Button></td>
    </tr>)
  }

  export default renderCadastros
```

*Component that creates the form and has the function to add a new value to its parent state:*

```js
import './App.css';
import React, {useState, useRef} from 'react';
import {Button, Form, Col} from 'react-bootstrap'

function Formulario ({atualizarCadastros}){

  const [novoCadastro, setCadastros] = useState()
  
  const refId = useRef()
  const refNome = useRef()
  const refCpf = useRef()
  const refRg = useRef()
  const refNascimento = useRef()
  const refSexo = useRef()

  function registrarCadastros(){
    const id = refId.current.value
    const nome = refNome.current.value
    const cpf = refCpf.current.value
    const rg = refRg.current.value
    const nascimento = refNascimento.current.value
    const sexo = refSexo.current.value

    setCadastros({'id': id, 'nome': nome, 'cpf': cpf, 'rg': rg, 'data_nasc': nascimento, 'sexo': sexo})

    atualizarCadastros(novoCadastro)
  }

  return(
    <div>
    <Form>
    <Form.Row>
      <Col>
        <Form.Label>Identificação</Form.Label>
        <Form.Control ref={refId} placeholder="Id" />
      </Col>
      <Col>
        <Form.Label>Nome Completo</Form.Label>
        <Form.Control ref={refNome} placeholder="João Silva" />
      </Col>
      <Col>
        <Form.Label>CPF</Form.Label>
        <Form.Control ref={refCpf} placeholder="000.000.000-00" />
      </Col>
      <Col>
        <Form.Label>RG</Form.Label>
        <Form.Control ref={refRg} placeholder="0.000.000" />
      </Col>
      <Col>
        <Form.Label>Data de Nascimento</Form.Label>
        <Form.Control ref={refNascimento} placeholder="DD/MM/AAAA" />
      </Col>
      <Col>
        <Form.Label>Sexo</Form.Label>
        <Form.Control ref={refSexo} placeholder="Masculino/Feminino" />
      </Col>
    </Form.Row>
    </Form>
    <div  style={{display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column', alignItems: 'center'}}>
      <Button onClick={registrarCadastros} style={{margin: '10px'}} variant="primary">Cadastrar</Button>
    </div> 
  </div>
  )  
}

export default Formulario
```

Comment: `renderCadastros` is not a component, it is just a function. Why don't you make it one?

Comment: I cant see how i would make it a component and call it in my parent where it's {Cadastros.map(renderCadastros)} . sorry, i'm a beginner react learner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### return array of array problem

I think this function should little fix.

the function right now:

```
  function atualizarCadastros(novoCadastro){
    setCadastros(cadastrosAtuais => {
      return [cadastrosAtuais, novoCadastro]
    })
  }
```

when we call atualizarCadastros({ c: 3 }),
and we have cadastrosAtuais = [{ a: 1 }]

we get new Cadastros as `[[{ a: 1 }], { c: 3 }]`.

but we want to get `[{ a: 1 }, { c: 3 }]`

so we can use spread syntax:

```
function atualizarCadastros(novoCadastro) {
  setCadastros(cadastrosAtuais => {
    return [...cadastrosAtuais, novoCadastro];
  })
}
```

or better use concat:

```
function atualizarCadastros(novoCadastro) {
  setCadastros(cadastrosAtuais => {
    return cadastrosAtuais.concat(novoCadastro);
  })
}
```

Comment: thank you very much, it made the fix i needed. So just to clarify: in return [...cadastrosAtuais, novoCadastro]; the "..." makes that all the values are inside just one array? and using the .concat makes the same thing but it just concat the previous value to the new one? thank you again!

Comment: welcome! amm yes the "..." are spread the itmes of the array as a signals (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)
the concat return new array. (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)

Answer (score 1):

when you write like this

```
setCadastros({'id': id, 'nome': nome, 'cpf': cpf, 'rg': rg, 'data_nasc': nascimento, 'sexo': sexo})

atualizarCadastros(novoCadastro)
```

novoCadastro contains an old one as its value was read before setCadastros was called, so you can create an object and pass it to both: local state handler and to parent component function

```
const superNovoCadastro = {'id': id, 'nome': nome, 'cpf': cpf, 'rg': rg, 'data_nasc': nascimento, 'sexo': sexo}

setCadastros(superNovoCadastro)
atualizarCadastros(superNovoCadastro)
```

Comment: now the error its gone, but i still have a issue with that. When the new value is set, the table adds a row with empty values, and then a row with the new values. But the old values of the parent state are gone, do you know why this is? again i beg your pardon for the level of the question, im beginning my react skills.